# How to open old under cabinet halogen light?

Tags: electrical

[image]

How do I open this to change the bulb?  It is an under cabinet 12v halogen fixture installed in 2001.

Comment: Does it have a model or part number written anywhere on it that we could use to look it up?

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried so far? On those type of lights, I've seen two different ways to get the light out. First method is to twist the glass counter-clockwise by pressing on it and twisting. It will then pull straight out giving you access to the bulb. The other method I've seen is where there is a tab and you put a screwdriver in and the center cartridge pulls out.

Once you get at the bulb, remember to never touch a Halogen or Xenon bulb with your bare finger. The oils from your skin can weaken the glass of the bulb and shorten its life. Use gloves or a cloth to hold the bulb when removing it from the package and inserting into the fixture.

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2me4L6_f7g) looks similar to your photo and shows how to open it using the screwdriver method.